# Collapse button for each row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Hey everyone i have collapse button in a list-group am trying to show details of each row in collapse the problem is am having the data from a web service so it's dynamic here's my code

```
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="l in list">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">

      <h5>{{l}} : </h5>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <select class="form-control">
          <option value="" selected>Not Passed</option>
          <option value="">Passed</option>
          <option value="">Ok</option>
          <option value="">Ko</option>

        </select>

        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-primary form-control" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="mycollapse">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
          </button>
        </span>


      </div>
      <div id="mycollapse" class="collapse">
        <br> add bug zdfsdfd
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</li>
```

as you can see am using ng-repeat to get the data from the api and display it in list-items in the list item i have a combobox and a button what i want when i want to  click at that button each item has it's own collapsed content not a lot of buttons who  only show one collapsed content thanks to any guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$index` with your `id` because `$index` is dynamic.

```
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="l in list">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">

      <h5>{{l}} : </h5>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <select class="form-control">
          <option value="" selected>Not Passed</option>
          <option value="">Passed</option>
          <option value="">Ok</option>
          <option value="">Ko</option>

        </select>

        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-primary form-control" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mycollapse_{{$index}}">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
          </button>
        </span>


      </div>
      <div id="mycollapse_{{$index}}" class="collapse">
        <br> add bug zdfsdfd
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</li>
```

Comment: :/ it didn't work even there's a missing # i added it but it didn't work

Comment: ps Thank you for your answer

Comment: **jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #mycollapse_$index** am getting this

Comment: Thank you @DININDU

Answer (score 1):

you need create your own collapse function. try this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">

        <h5>{{l}} : </h5>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="input-group">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option value="" selected>Not Passed</option>
                <option value="">Passed</option>
                <option value="">Ok</option>
                <option value="">Ko</option>

            </select>

    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-primary form-control" data-toggle="collapse" ng-click="collapse[$index]=!collapse[$index]">
          awdawd
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
      </button>
    </span>


        </div>
        <div ng-show="collapse[$index] == true">
            <br> add bug zdfsdfd
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```